# python reload can't find module from sys.modules

Tags: python, module, reload

I'm trying to reload module that's already loaded within sys.modules, but somehow, reload() doesn't seem to work. 
(compile()+load would work although, still I can't use that since it's code reload through twisted)

```
for loader, module_name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(main_module.__path__):
    if(not module_name in sys.modules):
       module = loader.find_module(module_name).load_module(module_name)
     else:
       module = sys.modules.get(module_name)
       #this is unhelpful
       #sys.path.append(module.__path__)
       #this works
       #imp.find_module(module.__name__, module.__path__)
       #this doesn't
       reload(module)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/celery/execute/trace.py", line 36, in trace
    return cls(states.SUCCESS, retval=fun(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task/__init__.py", line 232, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/__init__.py", line 172, in run
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myuser/Dropbox/job-pipe/job_pipe/apps/tasks/crawl.py", line 71, in crawl
    crawler = CrawlerScript()
  File "/home/myuser/Dropbox/job-pipe/job_pipe/apps/tasks/crawl.py", line 37, in __init__
    reload(module)
ImportError: No module named example
```

What's the proper way to reload? I thought it was caused by find_module, though it seems to work properly, and error is not helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you import the module?

Comment: the code importing the module is above it was imported with module = loader.find_module(module_name).load_module(module_name). Re-importing the module before reload doesn't help, reload still crashes

Comment: You should post the complete traceback, not just the exception.

Comment: Also, post a complete program, not a snippet.

Comment: What it looks like you're trying to do here is to import every module in the universe, or in some package, then re-execute any which have already been imported.  Many modules are not reload-safe, which is why rebuild has facilities for adding special hooks to modules which may need re-loading; it can't fix things for you automatically, it just provides tools for you to fix your problems yourself.  What you're doing here is executing massive piles of arbitrary code which we can't see, so speculating about the cause of the problem is difficult.

Comment: I've added the complete traceback. I doubt anything else in code would help. I'm not trying to load/reload every module in the universe, only  sub modules that have no dependencies to my main core modules.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have loaded a module, to reload it you must do

```
module = reload(module)
```